# Is there a way to use Rspec let! with a scope so it can be used across multiple examples?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm trying to figure out a good way to handle setting rspec memoized variables that will be cleaned up after a set of tests, but not after an individual test.

I'd like it to achieve something similar to the following, but with let or something similar that doesn't require me to be responsible for reverting the state back afterwards.

```
RSpec.describe person do
  before(:context) do
    @shared_value = create(:person)
  end
  after(:context) do
    @shared_value.destroy
  end

  it "test 1" do
    expect(@shared_value).to be_a(Person)
  end

  it "test 2" do
    expect(@shared_value).to be_a(Person)
  end
end
```

Using `let!` only provides a scope around each example.
Using a pattern like this raises an error for rspec

```
  let(:shared_person)
  before(:all)
    shared_person
  end
  it "test 1" do
    expect(shared_person).to be_a(Person)
  end
```

The around method only provides a scope around each example

Comment: Even with `let!`, you'd have to somehow call `destroy` when you're done. That's exactly what `before` / `after` are for.

Comment: Have you tried `RSpec.shared_context`?

Comment: This is really two different questions baked into one. Reusing `let/let!` and `before` blocks can be done via shared contexts. Resetting the database can be done via transactional fixtures and gems like database cleaner in older versions of rails.

Comment: I also asked for a feature on rspec core and was directed towards the let_it_be functionality of the test-prof gem. https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/issues/3065 https://github.com/test-prof/test-prof/blob/master/docs/recipes/let_it_be.md
At a glance it seems to do exactly what I asked, I'll be checking it out and if it works well I'll try to get around to providing it as an answer.

Comment: The readme for that gem is rife with warnings about state leakage between tests; it will result in flaky tests and potentially false passes for examples run on objects modified by other examples -- that is a dangerously unreliable way to implement testing. If the goal is to speed up your tests, look for areas where you can use `build` or `build_stubbed` instead of create actions, parallelize your test runs, avoid using let! in scenarios where it's not needed, and if you really want to clump together examples into a single expectation use the `aggregate_failures` matcher.

Answer (score 0):

It's erroring because you're not defining the object... the syntax works like this:

```rb
let(:my_variable_name) {
  # block that returns the object I want to assign to my variable
}
```

Your code is missing the block portion defining the object, and rspec is seeing everything else you've defined after that and getting confused. Your test should look something like this:

```rb
describe Person do
  subject { person }

  let(:person) { create :person }

  it { should be_kind_of(described_class) }
  it { should be_valid }
end
```

If you aren't using FactoryBot, then your person definition would look something like:

```rb
let(:person) { described_class.create(first_name: 'Spaghetti') }
```

Subject defines the object under test (making the `should` shorthand syntax work). Unless it's necessary for the object to exist before the example runs, you should lazy load it with `let`; if it's necessary for the object to exist *before* the example runs, then use `let!`. If you need to mix them, you can do something like this:

```rb
let(:person) { create :person }

context 'when person is lazy loaded' do
  it 'does not load the unused object' do
    expect(described_class.count).to eq(0)
  end

  it 'instantiates the object when it is referenced' do
    expect(person.class.count).to eq(1)
  end
end

context 'when person needs to exist before example' do
  let!(:person) { super() }

  it 'instantiates the object before running the example' do
    expect(described_class.count).to eq(1)
  end

  it 'does not create additional objects' do
    expect { person }.not_to change(described_class, :count).from(1)
  end
end
```

Use `context` blocks to encapsulate the test setup to simulate a specific scenario. Tests for public methods should be grouped in a `describe` block (i.e., `describe '.class_method_name' do` or `describe '#instance_method_name'`) with 0-or-more context-specific blocks inside if it.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. However, the question is not about how to fix the example code provided, rather if there is a syntax that does something to the effect described, so I can't accept this as an answer. The ideal solution to this is likely with the let_it_be functionality of the test-prof gem as mentioned in the comments. I have not gotten a chance to test it out yet, but if it works as described it should be a valid answer.

Comment: @SamuelFrost You wrote "Using a pattern like this raises an error for rspec" and then wrote invalid syntax (let declaration with no block arg) which rightly raises an exception so I explained the correct syntax fundamentals. You're upset that data is cleaned up between test runs? That helps ensure accurate tests; otherwise you can end up with tests falsely passing because one test is looking at an object that is in a dirty state / was modified by another test. If you want to validate multiple expectations inside the same block, use the `aggregate_failures` matcher.